# React initial state on input validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-hooks

I'm struggling my mind over than hour on how to set initial state on the validation input.

Here is my code example:

```js
const {useReducer, useEffect, useState} = React;

const BasicInput = props => {
 const [isValidated, setIsValidated] = useState(true)

 useEffect(() => {
   setIsValidated(props.validation)
      console.log(props.validation)
 },[props.validation])
 
 return (
  <div className='input-box'>   
   <input
        className={`${!isValidated && 'not-valid'}`}
    type='text'
    name={props.name}
    required
    onChange={props.handleInput}
   />
  </div>
 )
}

function contactFormReducer(state, action) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'email':
   return {...state, name: {
    value: action.payload,
    isValidate: /^.+(@).*\.[a-z]{2}$/.test(action.payload)
   }}
 }
}

const ExampleForm = () => {
 const [formData, dispatch] = useReducer(contactFormReducer, {
  name: {
   value: null,
   isValidate: false
  }
 })

 return ( 
     <BasicInput      
      name='email'
      label='label'
      handleInput={e => dispatch({type: 'email', payload: e.target.value})}
      validation={formData['name'].isValidate}
     />
 )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ExampleForm title="Example using simple hook:" />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.not-valid {
 border: 2px solid red;
 color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
</div>
```

As you can see, initial input state is set to not valid, which is okay, but it looks awful as for the form that is displayed for the first time. I.m wondering how to not set style `not-valid` and at the same time keep validation on false on the first render. I need some fresh insight on this, any help and advice much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Just after I made this post I found solution which is quite satisfied, but still I'm not happy with performance:

```js
const {useReducer, useEffect, useState} = React;

const BasicInput = props => {
 const [isValidated, setIsValidated] = useState(true)
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
  if (isFocus) {
   setIsValidated(props.validation)
      console.log(props.validation)
  }
 })

 const handleFocus = () => {  
  setIsFocus(true)
 }
 
 return (
  <div className='input-box'>   
   <input
        className={`${!isValidated && 'not-valid'}`}
    type='text'
    name={props.name}
    required
    onChange={props.handleInput}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
   />
  </div>
 )
}

function contactFormReducer(state, action) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'email':
   return {...state, name: {
    value: action.payload,
    isValidate: /^.+(@).*\.[a-z]{2}$/.test(action.payload)
   }}
 }
}

const ExampleForm = () => {
 const [formData, dispatch] = useReducer(contactFormReducer, {
  name: {
   value: null,
   isValidate: false
  }
 })

 return ( 
     <BasicInput      
      name='email'
      label='label'
      handleInput={e => dispatch({type: 'email', payload: e.target.value})}
      validation={formData['name'].isValidate}
     />
 )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ExampleForm title="Example using simple hook:" />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.not-valid {
 border: 2px solid red;
 color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
</div>
```

This solution is going to re-render my input component every time when `onChange` event is fired. Any idea how to prevent it?

Comment: You don't need `isValidated` at all.

Comment: @JonasWilms I need the initial state to be true, I can't rely on the state of parent component in that case